# How to solve problem with accuracy in decision tree algorithm

Tags: r

In our dataset we are apply decision tree algorithm to predict, there is a problem when i run the code every time again it's changes the accuracy

[image: This is our dataset]

```
heart<- read.csv("C:/Users/faris/Desktop/Project/heart.csv")
split = sample.split(heart$target, SplitRatio=0.7)
training_set_Dec= subset(heart,split==TRUE)
test_set_Dec= subset(heart,split==FALSE)
Fit_Test<- rpart(target ~. ,method = "class",data = training_set_Dec)
Fit_Test
rpart.plot(Fit_Test, box.palette="RdBu", shadow.col="gray", nn=TRUE)
# Prediction for Decision Tree Algorithm
pred_class<-predict(Fit_Test,test_set_Dec,type="class")
(Tab_Test_Dec <- table(pred_class, test_set_Dec$target,dnn=c("Prediction","Actual")))
confusionMatrix(Tab_Test_Dec)
Accuracy_Dec_Test <- sum(diag(Tab_Test_Dec))/sum(Tab_Test_Dec)
Accuracy_Dec_Test
print(paste('Accuracy for test Decision Tree Algorithm',
            Accuracy_Dec_Test))
```

Comment: Doest the file heart.csv get updated frequently, ie. in between runs of the algorithm?

Comment: i don't know what you mean

Comment: Is this heart.csv always the same, or is it updated frequently with more data? Could it that every time you run the script, it is using a heart.csv file containing more data than previously?

Comment: No heart.csv is not update with more data is always the same, but i think the problem when we are  run the split function in each time.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The sample.split() function uses random splitting. In order to make the random always produce the same, you may want to set the random seed at the beginning of your code, as: set.seed(1). It will make sure your code always behave the same, in a reproducible manner, but you will lose the chance to try different samples which may give different results.

Comment: if we are didn't use the set.seed(1), the our code it's correct to define the accuracy or not

Comment: Machine Learning algorithms do not have a precise, fixed accuracy. They'll try to guess the best they can, according to the data sample you provide. If you sample randomly, each time you have different data to learn from and different data to test, so results vary slightly.